# Problemas with VPN L2TP / IPSec connection

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I am trying to coonect to a VPN network using L2TP/IPSec connection with Shared Key.
I always have this error msg:

g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed

Here is the log:

opening file: /run/nm-l2tp-3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89/ipsec.conf
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: loading named conns: 3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 1, has_peer = 1
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: seeking_src = 0, seeking_gateway = 1, has_dst = 1
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst  via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0 src  table 254
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: set nexthop: 192.168.1.1
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 169.254.0.0 via  dev wlp1s0 src  table 254
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 192.168.1.0 via  dev wlp1s0 src 192.168.1.45 table 254
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 127.0.0.0 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 127.0.0.0 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 127.0.0.1 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 127.255.255.255 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 192.168.1.0 via  dev wlp1s0 src 192.168.1.45 table 255 (ignored)
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 192.168.1.45 via  dev wlp1s0 src 192.168.1.45 table 255 (ignored)
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 192.168.1.255 via  dev wlp1s0 src 192.168.1.45 table 255 (ignored)
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 0, has_peer = 1
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 0, has_dst = 1
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: dst 192.168.1.1 via  dev wlp1s0 src 192.168.1.45 table 254
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: set addr: 192.168.1.45
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9005]: seeking_src = 0, seeking_gateway = 0, has_peer = 1
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 002 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #1: initiating Main Mode
Oct 28 13:28:05 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 104 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate
Oct 28 13:28:06 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 003 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #1: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [5b362bc820f60008]
Oct 28 13:28:06 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 106 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
Oct 28 13:28:06 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 108 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
Oct 28 13:28:06 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 003 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #1: ignoring informational payload IPSEC_INITIAL_CONTACT, msgid=00000000, length=28
Oct 28 13:28:06 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 002 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #1: Peer ID is ID_IPV4_ADDR: '67.41.196.26'
Oct 28 13:28:06 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 004 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #1: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=PRESHARED_KEY cipher=AES_CBC_256 integ=HMAC_SHA2_256 group=MODP1024}
Oct 28 13:28:06 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 002 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #2: initiating Quick Mode PSK+ENCRYPT+PFS+UP+IKEV1_ALLOW+SAREF_TRACK+IKE_FRAG_ALLOW+ESN_NO {using isakmp#1 msgid:3beada0e proposal=AES_CBC_256-HMAC_SHA1_96, AES_CBC_128-HMAC_SHA1_96, 3DES_CBC-HMAC_SHA1_96 pfsgroup=MODP1024}
Oct 28 13:28:06 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 117 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: initiate
Oct 28 13:28:06 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 010 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: retransmission; will wait 0.5 seconds for response
Oct 28 13:28:07 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 010 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: retransmission; will wait 1 seconds for response
Oct 28 13:28:08 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 010 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: retransmission; will wait 2 seconds for response
Oct 28 13:28:10 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 010 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: retransmission; will wait 4 seconds for response
Oct 28 13:28:14 dellmint NetworkManager[9008]: 010 "3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: retransmission; will wait 8 seconds for response
Oct 28 13:28:15 dellmint nm-l2tp-service[8558]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Oct 28 13:28:15 dellmint NetworkManager[777]:   [1603902495.8107] vpn-connection[0x5614e206c2d0,3f3fc0d7-5044-4040-88cf-fd35f75eca89,"VPN connection 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)

Can you please help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, welcome to AskUbuntu.  You need to use the formatting tool to format the input in a more readable way.  Some basic help is just below in the editing box while [an exhaustive guide is here](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu <= 20.04, try the newer network-manager-l2tp packages from https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp . If you have anything in the Phase 1 & 2 input boxes, delete their contents. The newer nm-l2tp version use a combination of Win10 & iOS IKEv1 proposals for phase 1 & 2 instead of using the libreswan or strongswan default. If you are still have issues, try switching from strongswan to libreswan with `sudo apt install libreswan`